# Evaluate an expression stored in an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array which is interleaved with sign (+/-) and numbers.
Is there a way to evaluate this array in ruby?

e.g: `["+", 1, "+", 2, "+", 3]`. 
This needs to be evaluated, ie, to `6` in above case.

More examples:

```
["+", 1, "+", 2, "+", 3] ->  6
["+", 1, "+", 2, "-", 3] ->  0
["-", 1, "-", 2, "-", 3] -> -6
```

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far? Looks like homework.

Comment: Well you could `eval(["+", 1, "+", 2, "+", 3].join)` but you shouldn't...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the given array structure the code could be like

```
ar = ["-", 1, "-", 2, "-", 3]
ar.each_slice(2).inject(0) do |memo, slice|
  # memo.send(slice[0], slice[1])
  memo.send(*slice) # thanks @tadman!
end
# => -6
```

Comment: Even better, `send(*slice)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one liner

```
eval ["+", 1, "+", 2, "+", 3].map(&:to_s).reduce(:+)
```

> Note: negative effects of `eval` have not been taken into consideration
>   here.

Comment: `eval` is really a heavy handed approach here and should be discouraged.

Comment: and you can do `map(&:to_s)`

Comment: seems like there could be simple `join('')` instead of `map(&:to_s).reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other approaches one could take.

**#1**

```
def calc(arr)
   enum = arr.to_enum
   loop.reduce(0) { |val| val.send enum.next, enum.next }
end

calc ['+', 7, '+', 1, '-', 2, '-', 3, '+', 4]
   #=> 7
```

You could add operators (having two operands) other than `+` and `-` so long as the lack of parentheses is not a problem. You can't compute `((-1+4)*4)%5`, but you can evaluate `-1+4*4%5`:

```
calc ["-", 1, "+", 4, "*", 4, "%", 5]
  #=> 2
```

**#2**

```
def calc(arr)
  arr.each_slice(2).
      with_object({}) { |(op,val),h| (h[op] ||= []) << val }.
      values_at('+', '-').
      map { |a| (a || [0]).reduce(:+) }.
      reduce(:-)
end

calc ['+', 7, '+', 1, '-', 2, '-', 3, '+', 4]
  #=> 7
calc ['+', 7, '+', 1]
  #=> 8 
calc ['-', 2, '-', 3]
  #=> -5
```

The steps are as follows.

```
arr ['+', 7, '+', 1, '-', 2, '-', 3, '+', 4]
a = arr.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["+", 7, "+", 1, "-", 2, "-", 3, "+", 4]:each_slice(2)>
```

We can see the objects that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
a.to_a
  #=> [["+", 7], ["+", 1], ["-", 2], ["-", 3], ["+", 4]]
```

Continuing,

```
b = a.with_object({}) { |(op,val),h| (h[op] ||= []) << val }  
  #=> {"+"=>[7, 1, 4], "-"=>[2, 3]} 
c = b.values_at('+', '-')
  #=> [[7, 1, 4], [2, 3]] 
d = c.map { |a| (a || [0]).reduce(:+) }
  #=> [12, 5] 
e.reduce(:-)
  #=> 7
```

Comment: Solution #2 is pretty crafty but there can be problems if there are only `+` in array. And it would be nice to handle `*` and `/` too.

Comment: By the way in #1 you don't need `val =`, do you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out both problems. I fixed them in an edit. I also showed that #1 works with other operators, including, say, % and **, as well as * and /, provided there's no need for parentheses. It would be more interesting if you were using RPN. :-)